# weird array.length alternative syntax

Tags: javascript

this had me surprised:

```
var parts = email.split('@');
if (parts < 2) {
```

reference: https://github.com/Kicksend/mailcheck/blob/master/src/jquery.mailcheck.js#L21-22

essentially, it looks like:

```
var a = [null, null, null]
a < 2 // false

var b = [null]
b < 2 // true
```

so it seems like it works but I want to know why, what coercion actually happens for it to do this? as the intent here was to bail if less than 2 parts come from the email string, i would have expected it to always pass due to the array defined being truthy - it ought to create an array with at least 1 member even on an empty string.

i would always prefer to use `array.length`. is the above safe?

Comment: Well, `array.length` isn't always safe either considering that it doesn't always readjust when an element is deleted ;)

Comment: @JeffreySweeney - `.length` always represents the actual length of the array.  If an element is removed with something like `.splice()` or `.pop()`, then `.length` will immediately and reliably return the new length.  If you merely set an array element to undefined, that array element still exists and all the other array elements stay in their same locations so the `.length` value correctly does not change.  Can you describe when you think `.length` is not accurate.

Comment: thanks for the replies, sanity check done, issue filed, i am not going insane...

Comment: @jfriend00 `deleting` elements at the end of the array will not adjust the `length` property (perhaps intentionally), and there has been browser discrepancies in the past (http://hexmen.com/blog/2006/12/push-and-pop/). In addition, it is way too easy to change the property itself, and a fallacious framework or lazy programmer can cause a lot of confusion.

Comment: @JeffreySweeney - you make no sense.  So, how do you even propose to use an array if you don't use the `.length` property?  And, what do you recommend the OP do to solve their question.

Comment: @jfriend00 I was just making a point that the `length` property isn't always 100% reliable. I didn't mean to suggest that it shouldn't be used; I use it all the time :)

Comment: @JeffreySweeney - [the article you referenced](http://hexmen.com/blog/2006/12/push-and-pop/) is very old (more than 5 yrs old).  It talks about browsers that don't support array `.push()`.  The last browser I know of that didn't support that was IE5.  If you have an article that discusses deficiencies in `.length` with browsers actually in meaningful use today, I'd be happy to read that one.

Comment: @JeffreySweeney—length is absolutely reliable if you expect it to behave per ECMA-262. Note that *delete* isn't an Array method so it doesn't adjust the length. In any case, *length* is only ever specified to be larger than the highest index (within the allowed range), it is not guaranteed to be the number of elements in the array, or even specifically one higher than the largest index.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a string and then number conversion that's happening, since arrays can't be directy compared with the `<` operator. First it will do a string comparison but with the number it will then do a number comparsion.

Note that:

- `[null, null, null] == ",,"`
- `[null] == ""`

And:

- `+",,"` is `NaN`
- `+"" === 0`

Now it makes sense because `0 < 2 === true` but `NaN < 2 === false`.

It's therefore not a meaningful expression indeed. `[null, null] < 3` is `false` because `"," < 3` is essentially doing `NaN < 3`.

Comment: thanks, pretty much what i hoped it was. i had used nulls as an example but the result of the split of the string will always contain strings anyway.

Comment: @Dimitar Christoff: True; the only array that can survive an array -> string -> number conversion is an one-element array containing a number. E.g. `[2] < 3 === true`.

Answer (score 2):

Using the `<` or `>` operators to compare an array to a number is not safe, reliable or correct.  You should not do it.

Here are the conversion rules taken from [this O'Reilly book](http://dreamsoft.xhost.ro/Books/jscript/ch05_05.htm):

> The operands of these comparison operators may be of any type.
>   Comparison can be performed only on numbers and strings, however, so
>   operands that are not numbers or strings are converted. Comparison and
>   conversion occur as follows:
>
> If both operands are numbers, or if both convert to numbers, they are
>   compared numerically.
>
> If both operands are strings or convert to strings, they are compared
>   as strings.
>
> If one operand is or converts to a string and one is or converts to a
>   number, the operator attempts to convert the string to a number and
>   perform a numerical comparison. If the string does not represent a
>   number, it converts to NaN, and the comparison is false. (In
>   JavaScript 1.1, the string-to-number conversion causes an error
>   instead of yielding NaN.)
>
> If an object can be converted to either a number or a string,
>   JavaScript performs the numerical conversion. This means, for example,
>   that Date objects are compared numerically, and it is meaningful to
>   compare two dates to see whether one is earlier than the other.
>
> If the operands of the comparison operators cannot both be
>   successfully converted to numbers or to strings, these operators
>   always return false.
>
> If either operand is or converts to NaN, the comparison operator
>   always yields false.

In this particular case, since there is no conversion of an array to a number, it ends up comparing two strings which is completely unreliable.

This is yet another reason why you should only compare two items of the same type.  In this particular case, it's also much, much more readable code to use the `.length` property directly and use:

```
a.length > 2
```

Comment: `Array` doesn't have a `toNumber`, when converted to a number, an array is `NaN`.

Comment: yeah, in my port i do just that, length. i had filed a ticket over this and some guy tried to convince me it was actually ok so i thought i was missing out on a coercion of sorts. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I get the feeling that it's not safe, because:

```
[0, 0] > 1 // false
```

and

```
[0, 0] < Infinity // false
```

---

Okay, it's not comparing the number of elements at all. It compares the string representation of the array, hence `NaN < Infinity` giving `false`. So the answer is no, it's not at all a safe alternative because they don't do remotely the same thing. It only works for you because:

```
[null] < 2 -> null < 2 -> 0 < 2 -> true
```

but

```
[null, null, null] < 2 -> ',,' < 2 -> NaN < 2 -> false
```

Answer (score 1):

Arrays cannot be converted to numbers.  What's happening here is the arrays are being converted to strings.

When arrays are converted to strings, internally JavaScript does `array.join(',')`.

So, `['a','b']` becomes `"a,b"`.

`[null]` is `""` and `[null,null]` is `","`. This is because `null` is converted to a blank string.

So, `[null,null] < 2` is `"," < 2` which is false.

To get an array's length, use `.length`.

Answer (score 1):

Oh, its safe, it's just not comparing what you think its comparing.

The expression `parts < 2` is comparing an array to a number. To complete this comparison, JavaScript must convert these two values to a common type, and the only one available is string. The toString() method of the array object concatenates each of the string values of the arrays elements w/ a comma, and the string value of null is an empty string. So your test expressions are performing `",," < "2"` and `"" < "2"`, which I'm certain isn't what's intended.

As long as you don't use `delete` on the array (use `slice`, instead), using length should be perfectly safe.